# When testing a controller method how should you handle the scenerio when it calls a local method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I am using xUnit testing against a WebAPI controller. I have the following methods in my controller:

```
public string GetLoginMessage()
{
  var loginMessage = GetSystemSetting("LoginMessage", "Retrieving...");
  return loginMessage;
}

public string GetOwnerName()
{
  string ownerName = GetSystemSetting("OwnerName", "Retrieving...");
  return ownerName;
}

private string GetSystemSetting(string SettingName, string DefaultValue)
{
  var settingValue = DefaultValue;
  //var _systemSettingsBL = new SystemSettingsBL();
  var systemSettingInfoList = _systemSettingsBL.GetSystemSettings(0, 0);
  var setting = systemSettingInfoList.Where(w => w.Key == SettingName).FirstOrDefault();
  if (setting != null && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(setting.Value) == false)
  { settingValue = setting.Value; }
  return settingValue;
}
```

As you can see GetSystemSettings() gets called multiple times from various methods in the same controller.

I'm using a simple example here with GetLoginMessage() and GetOwnerName(). Is my logic right in assuming these three methods should be tested separately in isolation? If so, wouldn't I need to mock GetSystemSettings(). If so, how do I go about doing that?

My test thus far:

```
  public class AccountsControllerTests : BaseUnitTest
  {
    private readonly Mock<ICommonBL> _commonBLMock;
    private readonly Mock<ISystemSettingsBL> _systemSettingsBLMock;
    private readonly AccountsController _accountsController;

    public AccountsControllerTests()
    {
      _commonBLMock = new Mock<ICommonBL>();
      _systemSettingsBLMock = new Mock<ISystemSettingsBL>();
      _accountsController = new AccountsController(_commonBLMock.Object, _systemSettingsBLMock.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    private void GetLoginMessage_ShouldReturnString_WhenCalled()
    {
      //how to possibly mock local controller method GetSystemSetting()

      var loginMessage = _accountsController.GetLoginMessage();

      Assert.NotNull(loginMessage);
      Assert.IsType<string>(loginMessage);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Only public methods should be tested by unit tests. Your public methods in isolation are so trivial that I don't think a test will add much value. Only in combination with the private method are interesting. Because of that I think your test is already good.

Comment: Your test scenario depends on `_systemSettingsBL.GetSystemSettings` to have data and validation of it. So you should be focusing mocking it which you can do by defining setup method of `GetSystemSettings` on `_systemSettingsBLMock`. With that you can add the assert on `loginMessage` based on your mock data.

Comment: Thanks, yes I made the example very simple. What happens if GetLoginMesage() was more complex and definitely needed testing. Then GetLoginMessage and GetSystemSettings() have to be in the same test because GetSystemSettings is private? Or what if GetSystemSettings() was not private, how would that change things?

Comment: @Hank - if you mocking all external dependencies which are used by private or public methods then you can achieve the required testing. In your scenario even the method `GetSystemSettings` is private, but it is dependent on external object `_systemSettingsBL`, so if you are mocking `_systemSettingsBL` then you achieve the required test scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test scenario depends on `_systemSettingsBL.GetSystemSettings` to have data and validation of it. So you should be focusing mocking it which you can do by defining setup method of `GetSystemSettings` on `_systemSettingsBLMock`. With that you can add the **assert** on `loginMessage` based on your mock data.

In your test method GetLoginMessage_ShouldReturnString_WhenCalled, setup like below

```
_systemSettingsBLMock.Setup(
           s => s.GetSystemSettings(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>())
           .Returns( //return here the mock object of systemSettingInfoList which contains LoginMessage settingName  );
```